# Alphabetical order in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

```
Architecture
Bussiness
Computer Service
Documation
Electronic
Finance
ICT,Internet
Infrastructure
Manufacture
Medical
Others (Public office ,etc)
Trading Company
```

This is my option value order and I make it according to alphabetic order but I want "Others (Public office , etc) "in my last one . How could I change it to become it ???

Comment: where does that list come from? What did you try so far?

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this (in controller)

```
$list = $this->YourModel->find('all' , [
        'order' => [
            'title' => 'ASC'
        ]
    ])
->toArray();

$this->set(compact('list'));
```